# WTL CSplitterWindow cannot create more than 3 instances?

Tags: c++, wtl

I'm using WTL to create a window containing many splitted panes. The following will be the result.

```
---------------------------
|     |         |         |
|     |         |         |
|     |         |         |
|     |--------------------
|     |      |            |
|     |      |            |
---------------------------
```

There will be 4 splitters, three vertical ones and a horizontal one.

I followed the great article : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc7.aspx. 
But I only can add 3 splitters as below.

```
---------------------------
|     |         |         |
|     |         |         |
|     |         |         |
|     |--------------------
|     |                   |
|     |                   |
---------------------------
```

I tried a lot of ways but still cannot add the last one. 
Is is a bug of WTL? Can anybody help me?

Best regards,
Zach@Shine

Answer (score 4):

What is your problem? Is it a compile error, a runtime ASSERT, something else?

I strongly suggest that you derive your CMainFrame from [CSplitFrameWindowImpl<>](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/FrameX1.aspx).

```
--------------------------- 
|     |         |         | 
|     |   2TL   |  2TR    | 
|  1L |         |         | 
|     |-------------------- 
|     |  2BL |    2BR     | 
|     |      |            | 
---------------------------
```

The right pane (including all '2' panes) should derive from `CSplitterWindowImpl<CPane2, false>`, the right top pane (including all '2T' panes) should derive from `CSplitterWindowImpl<CPane2T, true>` as well as the right bottom one.

Each split pane should be created in the OnCreate() handler of it's parent and create it's children in it's own OnCreate().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it work. But I still don't know what happend. 

By the way, do you know how to create a Panel which can contain several child controls?
I've found CPaneContainer, but it only can contain one child.

Comment: We call that a non modal dialog :) Derive from ATL::CDialogImpl or WTL::CIndirectDialogImpl and from WTL::CDialogResize for sizing and positioning the controls when resized.